# Prevent undock computer in Windows

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista

In Windows Vista SP2 and in Windows 7 there is a new item in the Start menu: `Undock computer`.

In respons to the [`DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363212(VS.85).aspx) event I return `BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY` but the undocking function proceeds anyway. What is wrong?

A simple WindowProc to illustrate the problem:

```
LRESULT CMainWindow::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (message) {

        case WM_DEVICECHANGE: {
            switch (wParam) {
                case DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG : {
                    return BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CFrameWnd::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: is the 3rd line a typo? message, instead of event->Message()? >>>  switch (event->Message()) {

Comment: Sorry... The code has now been corrected. Thanks!

Comment: I have to agree with jalf - the message here is purely advisory; the user is undocking his computer and there's not a lot you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not say for certain, but I believe I read that Microsoft changed some things regarding sleep, hibernate, and maybe this undock although I didn't read about undock.

The change I recall reading about was that applications can no longer stop a laptop from sleeping. They get notified and about 1 second to do something, that is it.

Double check all of the above with MS documentation if you can find it.